# Parsing date with French month abbreviations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the date column containing dates with month abbreviations in French, such as:

```
u'18-oct.-2015'
u'12-nov.-2015'
u'02-d\xe9c.-2015'
u'26-janv.-2016'
u'02-f\xe9vr.-2016'
u'31-mai-2016'
u'01-juin-2016'
```

What is the proper way of using `to_datetime` to parse them?

Comment: If you can afford to use an external library, then - `df['date'].apply(lambda x: dateparser.parse(x))` would translate the date strings into their correct `datetime64` format. (*`pip install dateparser`* if you don't have it already installed)

Comment: @NickilMaveli No need for a lambda in this case. `df['date'].apply(dateparser.parse)`.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you can just set your locale:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR') # Windows may be a different locale name

# do your pandas read here
```

You might need to tell Pandas that that column is a datetime column... though it's also possible that you'll need to fix the column values - `jan` is the appropriate abbreviation for `janvier`. But Pandas may be smart enough to handle it.

Comment: This does not seem to work. Pandas was not able to detect the date format after changing the locale.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'french datetime':[u'18-oct.-2015',u'12-nov.-2015',u'02-d\xe9c.-2015',u'26-janv.-2016',u'02-f\xe9vr.-2016',u'31-mai-2016',u'01-juin-2016']})

# make a dictionary that maps the month name in french to a number
frenc_to_eng = {u'oct.': u'10', u'nov.':u'11',u'janv.':u'1',u'd\xe9c.':u'12',u'f\xe9vr.':u'2',u'mai':u'5',u'juin':u'6'}

# make new columsn for day month and year. FOr month, map the french name to month numbers
df['day'] = df['french datetime'].apply(lambda x : x.split('-')[0])
df['month'] = df['french datetime'].apply(lambda x : x.split('-')[1]).map(frenc_to_eng)
df['year'] = df['french datetime'].apply(lambda x : x.split('-')[2])

# make date time column from year, month and day.
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year']+'-'+df['month']+'-'+df['day'],format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='ignore')

print df
```

results in

```
  french datetime day month  year       date
0    18-oct.-2015  18    10  2015 2015-10-18
1    12-nov.-2015  12    11  2015 2015-11-12
2    02-déc.-2015  02    12  2015 2015-12-02
3   26-janv.-2016  26     1  2016 2016-01-26
4   02-févr.-2016  02     2  2016 2016-02-02
5     31-mai-2016  31     5  2016 2016-05-31
6    01-juin-2016  01     6  2016 2016-06-01
```